Can we create a global variable in autosys which gives as last day of previous month
I need to create a Global variable in autosys jil  which give me the last day of previous month,
command: sendevent -E SET_GLOBAL -G "Blackrock_CASHFLOWdate=date '+%Y%m%d'"
The above command give me the current date ,how to get the last day of previous month?
For Example if i am running the  job today which is on 06/27/2024 ,My GV should be created with the  value "20240531"
